# ckeditor 4 mentions: is it possible to not stop the process after the space?

Tags: ckeditor

I use mentions in my CKEDITOR 4 installation, and it works great.

However, I'm trying to autocomplete using full names, e.g. `John Smith`, but if there are a lot of Johns in the database, typing `@John` won't do it, and pressing space after that will close the suggestions box.

Is there a supported way to keep the process going even after a space character?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by adding a `pattern` to the settings.

`pattern: new RegExp("\@[_a-zA-Z0-9À-ž ]{2,}")`

The default pattern does not include the space, and looks like this:

`"\@[_a-zA-Z0-9À-ž]{2,}$"`